# Convert standard form of hyperbola to function form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I understand the concept of converting an equation of a hyperbola from general form into standard form, however I need to do the opposite. The equation is the following:

$$\frac{(x+8)^2}{5^2}-\frac{(y-8)^2}{6^2}=1.$$

I need to get $y$ by itself so I can type the equation into a calculator.

When I tried to solve this before, I did the square root on both sides, and I ended up with $y=\frac{58}{5}+\frac{6x}{5}$, which is a line and not a hyperbola.

Comment: $\$10$ says that somewhere you have written down $\sqrt{a + b} = \sqrt a + \sqrt b$.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha can solve these things for you. It can even graph it for you if that's what you were wanting to do. [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2B8%29%5E2%2F5%5E2-%28y-8%29%5E2%2F6%5E2%3D1).

Comment: What's the problem ? Once you develop $(y-8)^2$ it's just an equation in y (2nd degree) which has two solutions in general (not all hyperbolas represent a function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{(x+8)^2}{5^2}-\frac{(y-8)^2}{6^2}&=1\\
6^2(x+8)^2-5^2(y-8)^2&=5^2\cdot6^2\\
5^2(y-8)^2&=6^2(x+8)^2-5^2\cdot6^2\\
(y-8)^2&=\frac{6^2}{5^2}(x+8)^2-6^2
\end{align}$$

The mistake you likely did after here, was something like.

$$\begin{align}
(y-8)^2&=\frac{6^2}{5^2}(x+8)^2-6^2\\
y-8&=\frac65(x+8)-6
\end{align}$$

But as T. Bongers pointed out, $\sqrt{a+b}\neq\sqrt a+\sqrt b$.

Instead what you are better off doing is

$$\begin{align}
(y-8)^2&=\frac{6^2}{5^2}(x+8)^2-6^2\\
y-8&=\pm\sqrt{\frac{6^2}{5^2}(x+8)^2-6^2}\\
y&=8\pm\sqrt{\frac{6^2}{5^2}(x+8)^2-6^2}\\
y&=8\pm\frac65\sqrt{(x+8)^2-5^2}
\end{align}$$